# R csv file must be splitted in 3 data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, datatable, data-manipulation

[image]

I have this .csv file and I need to load it in 2 data frames or data tables (see image). How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `read.table()` function, which has the `skip` and `nrows` arguments. With `skip` you can skip as many rows as you want and with `nrows` you can say how many rows you want to read into R. Then you can use the function twice with those arguments in order to read the portions you want.

So you may use something like this:

```
first_table <- read.table(file = "your_file.csv", nrows = 5, sep = ",")

second_table <- read.table(file = "your_file.csv", skip = 7, sep = ",")
```